# Seekbar in listview returns first and last positon

Tags: android, listview, android-seekbar

[image]

Well, I'm having listview containing audio files, Audio playing is working fine but seekbar is not updating, when i click at any item! last position item seekbar is getting updating and playing. I didn't find the exact solution. Here is my code.

```
public class AudioAdapter extends android.widget.BaseAdapter
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    Uri uri;
    private Dialog dialog;
    TextView cur_val;
    Activity act;
    private Boolean isButtonClicked=false;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;
    private Context mcontext;
    AppUtils appUtils;
    MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listname;
    ProgressBar pb;
    int downloadedSize = 0;
    int totalSize = 0;
    String media,title;


    public AudioAdapter(Context context,Activity act, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> value)
    {
        mcontext=context;
        listname=value;
        this.act = act;

        // Memory Cache
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize)
        {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };

        appUtils = new AppUtils(mcontext);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listname.size();
   }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listname.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {


        convertView=View.inflate(mcontext, R.layout.audioreff, null);

        holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.audiotitle);
        holder.postedby=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postedby);
        holder.postedon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.likes=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
        holder.play=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.butplay);
        holder.seekBar=(SeekBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        holder.seekBar.setMax(99);
        holder.seekBar.setEnabled(false);

        convertView.setTag(holder);


        HashMap<String, String> result=listname.get(position);

        final String titlee=result.get("title");
        String postedy=result.get("postedby");
        String postedon=result.get("datetime");
        String likes=result.get("likes");
        final String medi=result.get("media");



        holder.title.setText(titlee);
        holder.postedby.setText(postedy);
        holder.postedon.setText(postedon);
        holder.likes.setText(likes);


        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; // toggle the boolean flag
                //   v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.buttonplay : R.drawable.pausebutton);
                showProgress();
                media=medi;
                title=titlee;
                Toast.makeText(mcontext,media+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("",AppConstantsUtils.BASE_URL+medi);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    downloadFile();
                }
            }).start();


            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }




    static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title,postedby,likes,postedon;
        Button play;
        SeekBar seekBar;
    }


      private void downloadFile(){

        try {
            URL url = new URL(AppConstantsUtils.BASE_URL+media);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            //connect
            urlConnection.connect();
            final String folder_main = "Apna";
            //set the path where we want to save the file
         /*   File SDCardRoot =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);

            if (!SDCardRoot.exists()) {
                SDCardRoot.mkdirs();
            }

            //create a new file, to save the downloaded file
            File file = new File(SDCardRoot,title);*/



            File wallpaperDirectory = new     File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);
      //have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    //create a File object for the output file
            final String perfection=title.replaceAll("\"","");
            File outputFile = new File(wallpaperDirectory, perfection+".mp3");
    //now attach the OutputStream to the file object, instead of a String representation






            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
            totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setMax(totalSize);
                }
            });

            //create a buffer...
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                // update the progressbar //
                act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                        float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalSize) * 100;
                        cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                    }
               });
            }
            //close the output stream when complete //
            fileOutput.close();
            act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    dialog.dismiss();



                    try{
                    mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Apna/"+perfection+".mp3");//Write your location here
                    mp.prepareAsync();
                  //  mp.start();
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.start();
                            mRunnable.run();
                        }
                    });


                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


        }
        });

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
        Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
        showError("Error : IOException " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        Log.d("dfdsfsd", e.toString());
        showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
    }
}

private void showError(final String err){
    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(mcontext, err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("dfdsfsd", err);
        }
    });
}

  private void showProgress(){
    dialog = new Dialog(mcontext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");


    cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
    cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
    dialog.show();

    pb = (ProgressBar)dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    pb.setProgress(0);
    pb.setProgressDrawable(mcontext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_progress));
}




private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mp != null) {

                //set max value
                int mDuration = mp.getDuration();
                holder.seekBar.setMax(mDuration);

                //update total time text view

                //set progress to current position
                int mCurrentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                holder.seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);

                //update current time text view

                //handle drag on seekbar
                holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        if(mp != null && fromUser){
                            mp.seekTo(progress);
                        }
                    }
                });


            }

            //repeat above code every second
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the **getView() method**

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
YourHolder holder=null;
if(convertView==null){
holder=new YourHolder();

convertView=View.inflate(mcontext, R.layout.audioreff, null);

holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.audiotitle);
holder.postedby=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.postedby);
holder.postedon=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
holder.likes=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.likes);
holder.play=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.butplay);
holder.seekBar=(SeekBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
holder.seekBar.setMax(99);
holder.seekBar.setEnabled(false);

convertView.setTag(holder);
}else{
holder=(YourHolder)convertView.getTag();
}

HashMap<String, String> result=listname.get(position);

final String titlee=result.get("title");
String postedy=result.get("postedby");
String postedon=result.get("datetime");
String likes=result.get("likes");
final String medi=result.get("media");



holder.title.setText(titlee);
holder.postedby.setText(postedy);
holder.postedon.setText(postedon);
holder.likes.setText(likes);


holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // isButtonClicked = !isButtonClicked; // toggle the boolean flag
        //   v.setBackgroundResource(isButtonClicked ? R.drawable.buttonplay : R.drawable.pausebutton);
        showProgress();
        media=medi;
        title=titlee;
        Toast.makeText(mcontext,media+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("",AppConstantsUtils.BASE_URL+medi);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            downloadFile();
        }
    }).start();


    }
});


return convertView;
```

}

> Don't make holder variable global. If you make it as global the last item value of getView is keep there. In the above case, that problem solved. Just read the holder mechanism in list view.

This will help you

Comment: holder=(YourHolder)convertView.getTag(); ! Thanks for your answer. What does it means?

Comment: Same Problem exists?

Comment: If i don't specify it global means, How do I  set seekbar on change listener?

Comment: Still same problem exits!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the `views` of a item of `ListView` global variables of the adapter. Because there is not only one item on the screen. If you make them global, the values of `these variables` will be filled with the `list-item` that will calls `getView` at last.

Instead you might keep them in `array` of `views`, and update corresponding `values` (like `position` of `seekBar`) on the basis of the `position`.

In short, your implementation is incorrect. First, you need to understand the working of `ListView`.